# One Dataset with multiple results sets (multiple select statements) SQL Reporting Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a question regarding the dataset usage in Reporting Services. I have a stored procedure which returns multiple select statements (result tables), and I created a Dataset in Reporting Services 2005 with this stored procedure. The problem is that I can not reference the second or third result table, and I can only use the first select statement fields. Is this the limitation on Reporting Services Dataset or is there a way to use multiple table results in one dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one set of results for a given dataset. To have multiple sets of results you need to have multiple datasets in SSRS.

(Strange that your question is word for word what was asked a few years ago: http://forums.asp.net/t/1220097.aspx/1 The answer hasn't changed. "If so, in report server project, the answer should be you can’t. Since the datasource property is for a single report, that is to say , it is for a table.")

An SSRS dataset is logically equivalent to a table: Fields/columns are defined, and all records must match that schema.